# Which is the better approach for filtering?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq, gridview

I have an ASP.net page containing a textbox, search button and a grid view.

Initially page will be loaded with all records binded to grid. Here, there is also another option for user, he can filter grid records by entering an id value in text box.

Since , on the page load , i am binding the grid with all the records. when ever user enters criteria for filtering in textbox, i am using linq query to filter it.

My grid has around 28,000 records.

Here, my question is which approach to follow. one approach is by passing id to database and fetch the result or just by querying dataset which is already available.

I am using LINQ approach, which seems like taking more time . or is it just my illusion?

Is there any differnece between two approaches? if so which is efficient?

Please clarify me on this..The LINQ query i am using is :

```
Var query = from myrow in dtItems.AsEnumerable()
                        where myrow.Field<string>("ID") ==txtID.Text
                        select myrow;
```

Comment: Can;t you just measure what is more efficient for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
Var query = from myrow in dtItems.AsEnumerable()
                        where myrow.Field<string>("ID") ==txtID.Text
                        select myrow;
```

Using [AsEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435.aspx) means that all of the records are loaded and the filter is applied to the in memory collection.

If you simply omit the `AsEnumerable` you should get a Queryable and the where is applied in SQL so you only load the matching rows.

However, if you're sure you already have the items in memory it should be faster to query them than call out to the database... you need to profile the code and see which works best.

Comment: Unless you have a reason for adding AsEnumerable I'd say it's an unnecessary step. It casts your collection so adds overhead (if only a small amount).

Comment: So I probably need to see more of your code to understand what's going on. Maybe try AsQueryable()..?